# Which writing systems does given character set cover

Tags: unicode, language-agnostic

What is the simplest way to figure out which writing systems (as in, Latin, Hebrew, Arabic, Katakana, Chinese characters) are supported by a given set of Unicode characters?

Comment: I guess it is wikipedia or i am misunderstood this question?

Comment: @nick_gabpe – programmatically. There’re arbitrary character sets coming in, and supported writing systems must be determined for each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect the `Script` and `Script_Extensions` properties of each character in the set, as documented in [UAX #24](http://unicode.org/reports/tr24/).

Comment: Thanks for useful link.

Answer (score 1):

**[Scripts and Blocks](http://unicode.org/reports/tr24/#Scripts_and_Blocks)**:

> Unicode characters are divided into non-overlapping ranges called
>   blocks [[Blocks]](http://unicode.org/reports/tr41/tr41-19.html#Blocks). Many of these blocks have a name derived from
>   a script name, because characters of that script are primarily encoded
>   in that block. However, blocks and scripts differ in the following
>   ways:
>
> - Blocks are simply ranges, and often contain code points that are unassigned.
> - Characters from the same script may be encoded in several different blocks.
> - Characters from different scripts may be encoded in the same block.
>
> As a result, using the block names as simplistic substitute for script
>   identity generally leads to poor results. For example, see Annex A,
>   Character Blocks, in Unicode Technical Standard #18, ["Unicode Regular
>   Expressions" [UTS18]](http://unicode.org/reports/tr41/tr41-19.html#UTS18).

Inside the latter document [[UTS18]](http://unicode.org/reports/tr41/tr41-19.html#UTS18), pay your priority attention to *Writing Systems Versus Blocks* in [Annex A: Character Blocks](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Character_Blocks).

Comment: Yeah, knowing the block is definitely not enough. So far it seems that running checks against individual characters is unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

At this point I’m leaning towards testing if enough glyphs from a script appear in the character set.

The approach would require two preparatory steps:

1. Put together a set of writing systems (scripts) supported by Unicode
2. For each script, define a character set containing characters of that script

Then I can solve the question “does character set A supports script X” by a test “are enough characters of script X’s character set also members of character set A”. If I do that for every script from step (1), I get a list of supported scripts.

The link provided by 一二三 references a [data file](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/Scripts.txt) that maps Unicode characters to their respective scripts, which would be invaluable in steps (1) and (2).